# Unable to add migration using Entity Framework and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell, code-first

I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 Express edition, upgrading from Visual Studio 2013 Express. I am now unable to update a database I have been using in one of my projects using code-first migrations. All I have changed is removing the `[Required]` data annotation from a property called "field" in a class called "Prospect".

I have tried upgrading Entity Framework to 6.2.3 and completely reinstalling it but neither has worked, I am currently using version 6.1.2.

In Visual Studio 2013 the 'Add-Migration' command worked fine but when trying to add the migration in visual studio 2015 the following error is produced in the package management console;

> PM> Add-Migration remove_required_field_from_prospect Unable to find
>
> type [NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerServices]. Make sure that
>   the assembly that contains this type is loaded. At
>   D:\Repos\PDintel\PDintel\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1004
>   char:5
>   +     $packageInstallerServices = $componentModel.GetService([NuGet.VisualStudio.I ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (NuGet.VisualStu...stallerServices:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   D:\Repos\PDintel\PDintel\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1006
>   char:5
>   +     $vsPackage = $packageInstallerServices.GetInstalledPackages() | ?{ $_.Id -eq ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At
>   D:\Repos\PDintel\PDintel\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:713
>   char:28
>   +     $toolsPath = Join-Path $installPath tools
>   +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At
>   D:\Repos\PDintel\PDintel\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:74
>   +     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsP ...
>   +                                                                          ~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   D:\Repos\PDintel\PDintel\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At
>   D:\Repos\PDintel\PDintel\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.2\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:810
>   char:20
>   +         (Join-Path $runner.ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll),
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

If you need any more info please ask!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***UPDATE***
This error seems to appear whenever I try and do anything using the Entity Framework, even 'Enable-Migrations' triggers it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but that error looks like an issue with the nuget package manager itself. After installing VS did you check to see if there were any updates? The package manager might just need to be updated.

Comment: There was an update about an hour ago or so, installing it now, I assume it was a bug as the command was working fine in Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web

Comment: After it updates try reinstalling entity framework then run your commands again. IVsPackageInstallerServices is what the package manager uses to install packages locally so EF may not have installed properly.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks Stephen!

Comment: No problem I hope it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug with the Package Management Console and has now been fixed!

Comment: Did you have to install an update to get it fixed? I get the same error in VS105u1

Comment: Yeah, installed the update and it all worked fine after that

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .nuget folder in your solution check the version of the nuget.exe Version there... A update of that was the fix in my case.